# why is it that my image appears momentarily on refresh and then disappears in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx, mern

I am building a shopping cart using MERN stack. The problem is that my images are not appearing, and on refresh the image appears only momentarily. it is showing me an icon that the image cannot be displayed. All my images are in the images folder inside src folder. Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../css/styles.css";
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  ModalFooter,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input
} from "reactstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import Cart from "./cart1.component";


export default class BookDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      book: [],
      modal: false,
      cover: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/books/" + this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ book: response.data, cover: response.data.cover });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  };

  AddToCart = e => {
    const { book } = this.state;
    let id = book._id;
    let cover = book.cover;
    let price = book.price;
    let qty = 1;
    let product = { id: id, cover: cover, price: price, qty: qty };
    let existing = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
    existing = existing ? existing : [];
    let val = existing.filter(item => item.id === id);
    if (existing.length !== 0) {
      if (val.length != 0) {
        existing.forEach(item => {
          if (item.id === id) {
            item.qty++;
          }
        });
      } else {
        existing.push(product);
      }
    } else {
      existing.push(product);
    }

    sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(existing));
  };
  getImages = cover => {
    let imagesURL = [
      "../images/csharp.jpg",
      "../images/css.jpg",
      "../images/javascript.jpg",
      "../images/json.jpg",
      "../images/lpthw.jpg",
      "../images/mongodb.jpg",
      "../images/node.jpg",
      "../images/php.jpg",
      "../images/python.jpg",
      "../images/sql.jpg"
    ];

    const bookUrl = `../images/${cover}`;
    let coverUrl = "../images/nocover.jpg";
    imagesURL.forEach(url => {
      if (url == bookUrl) {
        coverUrl = bookUrl;
      }
    });

    return coverUrl;
  };

  render() {
    const { book, quantity } = this.state;
    let src = this.getImages(this.state.cover);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <img src={src}></img>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <h2>{book.title}</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Category: {book.category}</li>
              <li>Author: {book.author}</li>
            </ul>
            <p className="button blue">${book.price}</p>
            <p>{book.description}</p>
            <button
              id={book._id}
              onClick={() => {
                this.toggle();
                this.AddToCart();
              }}
              className="btn btn-success"
            >
              Add to Cart
            </button>
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
              <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>My Cart</ModalHeader>
              <ModalBody>
                <Cart></Cart>
              </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I had been stuck on it for almost two days now. I tried using require in the src component but that is giving me an error that the ../images/nocover.jpg module cannot be found. Please, I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Can you copy me the line when you used require in src component?

Comment: sure!  <img src={require(src)}></img> this is the line and src variable  is initialized in the code, but this gives me an error.
Error: Cannot find module '../images/nocover.jpg'

Comment: Let's try a quick test by moving image folder inside src, so your url looks like this './images/nocover.jpg' (1 dot instead of 2 dot) with src={require(src)} code. It may be the problem of create-react-app settings. Can you try it?

Comment: now the error is Error: Cannot find module './images/nocover.jpg'

Comment: I have same issue. I tried using "require" and the images were displaying properly. But now Idk why it suddenly stopped displaying. Can anyone help with this issue even after using require. I also saw the console and there was no error, but It displayed this in the console.... " [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS..."